# Copying a spreadsheet values to a new sheet monthly

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, backup

I am trying to create a backup function for my spreadsheet using Google script editor,
am using the following code that I found in Github:

```
function makeCopy(){

 var formattedDate= Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"GMT","yy:mm:dd''HH:mm:ss");

 var saveAs =  "Copy " + formattedDate;

 var destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID");

 DriveApp.getFileById(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId())
 .makeCopy(saveAs,destinationFolder);

 }
```

but I have two problems:

- I can't use it with a sheet that uses IMPORT-AGE.
- I don't want to get an active spreadsheet, instead I want to use the sheet's ID and am not sure how to do that.

Comment: I solved the second problem. still trying to figure out the first one.

Comment: Create a new spreadsheet file and copy the values from the original one.

Comment: @Mario I want to do it with a script, so I can add a time trigger.

Comment: I was referring to a script, not to a manual approach. Check my answer :)

Comment: I guess I'll just use the original sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

**Unfortunately:**

- `importranges` can not be allowed programmatically. So you need to set get the values from the source spreadsheet and paste them to the newly created (target) spreadsheet.
- `copyTo` can not be used between two different spreadsheets, so you can use `getValues` and `setValues` instead.
- The logic is to iterate over the source sheets and for every sheet get values and copy them to the corresponding target sheets.

**Additional Modification points:**

- In the date object, you specified `"yy:mm:dd''HH:mm:ss"` but `mm` gives the minutes. In the first set of strings I think you want to get the month, therefore use `MM` instead. Check also the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) regarding the dates.
- Instead of passing a hardcopy value `GMT` get the timezone of your spreadsheet file by using [getSpreadsheetTimeZone()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSpreadsheetTimeZone()) instead.

With the above modifications, you have:

```
const formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),source_ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),"yy:MM:dd''HH:mm:ss");
```

### Solution:

```
function makeCopy() {
  const source_id = "SpreadsheetID"; // add the id of the spreadsheet to copy
  const source_ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(source_id);
  const formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),source_ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),"yy:MM:dd''HH:mm:ss");
  const saveAs =  "Copy " + formattedDate;
  const destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("FolderID"); // add the destination folder ID
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById(source_id).makeCopy(saveAs, destFolder);
  const target_ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());
  const source_sheets = source_ss.getSheets();
  const target_sheets = target_ss.getSheets();
  source_sheets.forEach((sh,i)=>{
     let values = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
     target_sheets[i].getRange(1,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values);
     SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe soMario's answer is correct, but I don't think you need to do all that copying at the end...

```
function makeCopy(source_ID) {

  // const source_id = "SpreadsheetID"; (pass the ID via a function?)

  const source_ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(source_ID);
  const formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),source_ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),"yy:MM:dd''HH:mm:ss");
  const saveAs =  "Copy " + formattedDate;
  const destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("FolderID"); // add the destination folder ID
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById(source_id).makeCopy(saveAs, destFolder);
  
  // You may want to do something with the new file's ID (like save the ID somewhere on the sheet you called this from
  // Logger.Log(file.id);
}
```

I am pretty sure this doesn't do anything productive:

```
  const target_ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());
  const source_sheets = source_ss.getSheets();
  const target_sheets = target_ss.getSheets();
  source_sheets.forEach((sh,i)=>{
     let values = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
     target_sheets[i].getRange(1,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values);
     SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  })
```

Comment: I don't think you carefully read my answer but you only copied a part of it and you posted it as your solution. While this is fine the OP mentioned that he has an `importrange` in his source sheet. That means, if you copy only the file, the data from the importranges **won't be copied** because in the new file the user needs to manually allow the `importrange`. This is why we copy the values with the part of the code you are pretty sure it is not needed. This problem is described in both the question but also in my answer. I downvote because your answer does not answer OPs question in any way.

Comment: Ahh, yup I missed that part. I assumed it's fine to just keep it as importrange formulas.

Comment: `I can't use it with a sheet that uses IMPORT-AGE.`